# How to stub HTTP POST request in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, rspec

I have a controller which contains a method and some conditional statements. the following is a sample of that controller.

```
class <controllername> < ApplicationController
def method
  if params["c"]
   http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
   req = Net::HTTP::Post.new("api_url_here")
   response = http.request(req)
   array = JSON.parse(response.body)
   url = params["s"]
   .....
  elsif params["e"]
   .....
  else
   .....
  end
end
end
```

I wrote rspec for the above controller

```
it "should do something" do
   array ="some array values"
   get :method, {"c" => "value for c", "s" => "value for s"}
   expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
end
```

I know the above rspec method is completely wrong. when this case runs the value for `array` and `response` are obtained by `post` call inside `method` and the `response` is `HTTPBADREQUEST` as expected.

**What I want is**

To stub those values for array and response in the spec case(these values will be needed for later operations) and my spec case to not call HTTP::POST inside the `method`

Comment: https://medium.com/finc-engineering/managing-http-requests-in-rails-rspec-test-aa2876dd646f seems like a good place to start?

Answer (score 3):

you can mock the answer

```
expect_any_instance_of(Net::HTTP::Post).to receive(:request) { response_data_here }
```

You can also use VCR: https://github.com/vcr/vcr

When you run VCR for the first time, it will do the real request and save the response as a fixture, the second time it will use the fixture and avoid the real http request

Comment: It is important to note that rspec developers discourage use of ```expect_any_instance_of``` - http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-1/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance .

Comment: You should use `allow_any_instance_of`

Comment: @bonafernando since RSpec 3.3, `any_instance` is deprecated and not recommended to use in your tests.

From the docs:
"any_instance is the old way to stub or mock any instance of a class but carries the baggage of a global monkey patch on all classes. Note that we generally recommend against using this feature."

Answer (score 2):

VCR is pretty handy, but since it always runs the real request the first time it's not as flexible in allowing you to mock any response that you like.

Try [fakeweb](https://github.com/chrisk/fakeweb), which lets you do just that. You can mock all requests to your URL like:

```
FakeWeb.register_uri(:get, "http://my-url.com", :body => "my mock response")
```

It doesn't seem to have been updated for over a year, but should still work for Rails 3 and 4.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to cleanly mock out http, req, or response because they are local variables. Consider making them class or instance variables such that you can override them.

Better yet, use the right tool for the job. I recommend using vcr tests so that you can mock out the entire HTTP stack. With VCR, you can record a request and play it back in your tests so you can get the exact mocked out data that you.

https://www.relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/2-9-3/docs/getting-started

Comment: Thanks! .but, if I want to mock only `array` in a way that `array = JSON.parse(response.body)` won't be called and only the values that I am setting using the mock will be used what should I use.

Comment: My reply will still be the same. The variable ```array``` is still a instance variable and is not exposed for mocking out. VCR really will be your best bet for properly testing the whole system.